# Seeking Efficient Solutions for Accessing Repository Files in GitHub Worker

Tags: php, performance, github, github-actions

I have a PHP program that creates an SQLite database and subsequently modifies it multiple times. Locally, everything works perfectly fine, but the entire system doesn't function properly on GitHub. For instance, when I use **`getcwd()`** to retrieve the working path, in my case, it points to **`/home/runner/work/oci-arm-host-capacity/oci-arm-host-capacity`**. However, the database stored under this path gets deleted after each run.

I haven't found a way to disable this cleanup, and I don't think it's feasible either, as it could potentially allow users to store large files on the GitHub worker, utilizing it as a storage service.

Therefore, I need to download the file using the GitHub API, save it in the worker directory, make modifications, and then upload it again (I also need to explore and integrate the GitHub API into my PHP project). I must admit, this sounds like an inefficient solution. Does anyone perhaps have a better suggestion/solution?

Comment: There's no "cleanup" as such; each run is in an entirely independent, containerised environment. If you need to store state long term, consider an _actual DB_ you can connect to (but be aware of parallel runs, state leaks, etc.).